# Custom HTML Element In LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

In our company, we have a web application. We are using community which will be launched through that Web App. When the community is launched from the Web App, we have to align it according to the Web App Header. In simple words, we have to have same header as the Web App. Now the Web app dev team has provided me with this HTML code which I have to add to my community:

```
<Script src="some JS hosted outside SF"></script>
<cust-header></cust-header>
```

I used this code in the VF page and added that VF on the community. However, there is one menu item on the header which has submenus which opens up downwards like a dropdown. And I am not able to see those dropdown menu options as the VF is rendered as an iFrame and occupy a specific region. I tried adding z-index without any success. So I wanted to try it out with LWC to see if it works. Seems custom elements are not supported within LWC. So I tried using document.createElements and see if it works. But it seems the HTML code itself is not getting compiled. Below is my JS Code:

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import { loadScript, loadStyle } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
import mchdr from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/mccheaderr';
export default class TestCommHead extends HTMLElement {
        constructor(){
                super();
                this.attachShadow({ mode: "open" });
                const span = document.createElement("cust-header");
                this.shadowRoot.appendChild(span);
        }
        
}
window.customElements.define("cust-header", TestCommHead);
```

And the HTML code:

```
<template>
  <cust-header></cust-header>
</template>
```

Am I doing anything wrong here? Is there any alternative where I can use custom elements in LWC? Thanks for your help!

Comment: As per my understanding attachshadow and customelement.define are not supported because of lightning locker and moreover via createElement you can only create simple html elements when usng lwc:dom ="manual" alongside it

Comment: Thank you @elijah!

Comment: Well , I think i should have posted it as answer, didnt know comments are not counted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do several of the things you are attempting to do in Salesforce.

for starters, here is the official doc on [including 3rd party libraries](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.js_third_party_library) from SF LWC.

then, the only way to add children nodes to an element is with the `lwc:dom="manual"` [directive](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/reference_directives).

As per using custom components:

[Third-Party Web Components](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/security_locker_custom_elements)

> To prevent security risks, you can’t use third-party web components on
> the Salesforce platform.
>
> Web components are custom elements. To define a custom element, you
> must use the customElements.define API. However, this API is global,
> and allows you to globally register a component name. Registering a
> name globally is a security risk because an attacker could register
> any name and take over the page. Lightning Locker’s SecureWindow
> wrapper blocks the customElements methods that create custom web
> components.
>
> The SecureWindow wrapper list in the Locker API Viewer tool shows that
> customElements is not supported.

Comment: It might be helpful to note that it's not a LWC restriction, it's a Salesforce restriction. In LWC OSS, you can use whatever kind of component you want that's compatible.

Comment: indeed - amended to specify that this is within Salesforce, instead of LWC

Comment: Thank you @glls and Brian!

Comment: In addition to your answer one should always look at API allowed by locker services there are many things blocked, one can simply search and checks if its allowed